# Burninate [intro]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Simply put, [intro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intro) is the very definition of a [meta-tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/meta-tags/info).  It's being used to refer to questions that are for people who have just begun programing.  It was created in '08 with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669/resources-for-getting-started-with-web-development), now closed as off-topic, and has amassed 68 questions over the years.

Comment: Out with intro!

Comment: Agreed. Cast it in(r)to the abyss.